# Date input is displayed wrong when width is set

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to generate a date input field with a width of 150 pixel (that has my wanted line behavior depending on the width of the screen).

And it works great on Mac/Chrome (See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4X23/3/)), but when I execute it on Android, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot from Android]

It is in the middle because the text-align is set to right. `150px` would be about where the `1983` ends.

Am I doing something wrong? or is it the browser? in that case, is there a workaround?

PS: It also works on Mac/Firefox and Mac/Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media query is making the date field have a 100% width. If you want this to change, change the width in the media query.

```
@media all and (max-width: 410px) {
    .dispInline {
        text-align: left;
        width:100%;
    }    
    .dispInlineDate {
        width: 150px;        
    }
}
```

Comment: It only is changing the width of the div that contains the date input field

Comment: I don't want the text aligned to the left. I want it displayed with a width of 150px on Android, just like it does on Mac/Chrome.

Comment: If I wanted it aligned to the left, it would be easier to remove `text-align:right` from its style

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I have updated the answer. Please note that inline-styles are considered bad practice.

Comment: Here is the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4X23/4/) with your answer. If you change the width of the window a bit, you will see why this won't work for me.

Comment: The behavior is already as I want it, it just is wrong on Android. Why and how to solve it is the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have set at the .css:

```
.dispInlineDate {
    float:none;      
}
```

and removed `width:150px;`from the inline styling. Setting it breaks the text position.

Now it works. Also, another div with 150px can be set around, then it would be exactly 150px.